# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read при записи *.xlsx файла

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

```js
const Excel = require('exceljs');
const fs = require('fs');

function checkFileAvailability(str) {
    if (fs.existsSync(str)) {
        return str;
    } else {
        return './images/no_image.jpg'
    }
}


exports.createXLSXFiles = async function createXLSXFiles(map, data) {
    let props = [
        {header: 'Изображение', key: 'img', width: 100},
        {header: 'Полное название', key: 'title', width: 30},
        {header: 'Род. каталог', key: 'parent', width: 30},
        {header: 'Артикул товара', key: 'vendorCode', width: 15},
        {header: 'Цена', key: 'cost', width: 15},
        {header: 'Код производителя', key: 'manufacturerCode', width: 20},
        {header: 'Полное описание', key: 'description', width: 300}
    ]
    for (let catalog of map.keys()) {
        const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        let arrayOfSheets = map.get(catalog);

        if (!arrayOfSheets.length) {
            let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(transformString(catalog), {
                properties: {
                    defaultRowHeight: 500,
                }
            })
            worksheet.columns = props;
            worksheet.getRow(1).height = 15;
            const productsForSheet = data.filter(val => val.parent === catalog)
            for (let i = 0; i < productsForSheet.length; i++) {
                let path = checkFileAvailability(`./images/${productsForSheet[i].imgSrc.split('/').pop()}`);
                let imageToPaste = workbook.addImage({
                    filename: path,
                    extension: "jpeg"
                });
                worksheet.addImage(imageToPaste, {
                    tl: {col: 0, row: 1.1 + i},
                    ext: {width: 500, height: 500},
                    editAs: 'undefined'
                });
                worksheet.addRow(productsForSheet[i]);
            }

        } else {
            arrayOfSheets.forEach(el => {
                let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(transformString(el), {
                    properties: {
                        defaultRowHeight: 500,
                    }
                })
                worksheet.columns = props;
                worksheet.getRow(1).height = 15;

                const productsForSheet = data.filter(val => val.parent === el)
                for (let i = 0; i < productsForSheet.length; i++) {
                    const path = checkFileAvailability(`./images/${productsForSheet[i].imgSrc.split('/').pop()}`);
                    let imageToPaste = workbook.addImage({
                        filename: path,
                        extension: "jpeg"
                    });
                    worksheet.addImage(imageToPaste, {
                        tl: {col: 0, row: 1.1 + i},
                        ext: {width: 500, height: 500},
                        editAs: 'undefined'
                    });
                    worksheet.addRow(productsForSheet[i]);
                }
            })
        }
        try {
            await workbook
                .xlsx
                .writeFile(`./${catalog}.xlsx`)
                .then(() => console.log('Saved'))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Ошибка в каталоге ${catalog}`, e);
        }

    }
}

function transformString(str) {
    if (str.length > 31) {
        return str.split(' ').map(el => el.substring(0, 3) + '. ')
            .join('');
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Имеется код, который должен производить сохранение *.xlsx файла. Данные по названию файла, названию листов в книге беру из Map, ключом которой является строка (она задает название файлу), а значением должен быть массив строк(каждый элемент массива строк должен задавать название листа в файле).
По итогу получаю ошибку EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory read. Прошу прощения за плохой код. Пишу как умею, на данный момент. Однако понять не могу, какая причина может вызвать эту ошибку по которой нода пытается произвести операции с директории характерные файлу? Если есть идеи, какие изменения можно внести в код, чтобы понять причину возникновения ошибки - буду рад их прочитать.
Для пояснения ясности - могу предоставить необходимые исходные данные

Comment: Посмотрите тут причины возможно поможет https://www.mmbyte.com/article/6398.html#:~:text=EISDIR%20stands%20for%20%22Error%2C%20Is,done%20the%20error%20is%20thrown.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Спасибо, файла .npmrc не нашел. Рабочая машина на которой запускается код на Win10(Для информации про права доступа через терминал). Но идей пока нет как отловить причину возникающей ошибки. Отсюда не могу понять с какой директорией проблемы. Может быть console.log() добавлять на каждой строке где объявляется переменная...?

Comment: Добавляйте логи конечно чтоб понять где после чего проблема. и пристреливайтесь

Comment: вариант только один let path = checkFileAvailability(`./images/${productsForSheet[i].imgSrc.split('/').pop()}`); Если вместо файла там будет каталог то дальше по логике

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как посоветовал Aziz Umarov, после добавления логов - проблема была на стороне приходящих данных, которые из-за моей безответственности, никак не обрабатывались. Добавил проверок в нужных местах на корректность адреса хранения файла.